# Getting grooves of equal width

Tags: modeling, measurement

How can I get a groove of uniform width, both horizontally and vertically, on a door (a plane)?

I've used edge loops, subdividing the surface and the knife tool but I can't get the groove to be a consistent thickness (6mm).

[image]
[image]

One value is about 736 and other is 730, which is close but not exact.

Answer (score 1):

**I would use the *bevel* tool.**

In edit mode, place one loop cut where you want each groove.  Then select the edge loops and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and drag to what ever width you want the groove.  The bevel tool splits each selected edge into two edges connected with a face.

Comment: oh yes...the bevel command. Also it would handle accuracy issue as well. but the problem is

Comment: but the problem is that corners are tapered. Can i have sharp corners?